# Execute Bash script remotely via cURL

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have a simple Bash script that takes in inputs and prints a few lines out with that inputs

**fortinetTest.sh**

```
read -p "Enter SSC IP: $ip " ip && ip=${ip:-1.1.1.1}
printf "\n"

#check IP validation
if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "SSC IP: $ip"
  printf "\n"
else
  echo "Enter a valid SSC IP address. Ex. 1.1.1.1"
  exit
fi
```

[image]

I tried to upload them into my server, then try to run it via `curl`

[image]

I am not sure why the input prompt never kick in when I use cURL/wget.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Does it have to be a prompt? Seems like a url parameter would be simpler.

Comment: curl used via wget isn't a terminal emulator allowing prompt/response, it is a is getter of data (one way). You'll need to add the SSC IP input via the curl command (ie. `curl ..sh < 1234 | bash`)

Comment: @PrestonM : I don't mind use your suggestion, sound way better than what I am trying to do right now, but I'm not sure how to adjust my code to use read from URL params. wanna get me started with a few lines ?

Comment: @RandyCasburn, do you mind answer it ? you suggestion might works in term of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ihue - please check my answer - that should work for you

Comment: I don't recommend running the script directly from `curl` in the first place. Good security dictates you download the script first, examine it to make sure it is the script you expect, *then* execute it. `curl ... > tmp.sh; <look at it>; bash tmp.sh`.

Answer (score 17):

With the `curl ... | bash` form, bash's stdin is reading the script, so stdin is not available for the `read` command.

Try using a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to invoke the remote script like a local file:

```
bash <( curl -s ... )
```

Comment: Very nice! That definitely addresses what I mentioned!

Comment: What happens if remote resources are required during execution?

Comment: Then downloading the script is clearly the wrong solution. You'd want `ssh -t user@host 'bash script.sh'`

Comment: @glennjackman - can you please give example with script or proof ?  I've tried it. Not seem to work. I'm not sure what I miss.

Comment: "doesn't work" is a useless problem description. Provide details.

Comment: `bash <(curl -s https://my_name.github.io/my_repo/setup.sh)` worked like a charm on macOS HighSierra(OSX10.13.6) with bash v3.2.57. THX!

Answer (score 12):

Your issue can be simply be reproduced by run the script like below

```
$ cat test.sh | bash
Enter a valid SSC IP address. Ex. 1.1.1.1
```

This is because the bash you launch with a `pipe` is not getting a `TTY`, when you do a `read -p` it is read from `stdin` which is content of the `test.sh` in this case. So the issue is not with curl. The issue is not reading from the tty

So the fix is to make sure you ready it from tty

```
read < /dev/tty -p "Enter SSC IP: $ip " ip && ip=${ip:-1.1.1.1}
printf "\n"

#check IP validation
if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "SSC IP: $ip"
  printf "\n"
else
  echo "Enter a valid SSC IP address. Ex. 1.1.1.1"
  exit
fi
```

Once you do that even `curl` will start working

```
vagrant@vagrant:/var/www/html$ curl -s localhost/test.sh | bash
Enter SSC IP:  2.2.2.2

SSC IP: 2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer `source <(curl -s localhost/test.sh)` option. While it is similar to `bash ...`, the one significant difference is how processes handled.

`bash` will result in a new process being spun up, and that process will evoke commands from the script.
`source` on the other hand will use current process to evoke commands from the script.

In some cases that can play a key role. I admit that is not very often though.

To demonstrate do the following:

```
### Open Two Terminals
# In the first terminal run:
echo "sleep 5" > ./myTest.sh
bash ./myTest.sh

# Switch to the second terminal and run:
ps -efjh

## Repeat the same with _source_ command
# In the first terminal run:
source ./myTest.sh

# Switch to the second terminal and run:
ps -efjh
```

**Results should look similar to this:**

Before execution:

[image: before]

Running `bash` (main + two subprocesses):

[image: bash]

Running `source` (main + one subprocess):

[image: source]

**UPDATE:**
*Difference in use variable usage by `bash` and `source`:*

`source` command will use your current environment. Meaning that upon execution all changes and variable declarations, made by the script, will be available in your prompt.

`bash` on the other hand will be running in as a different process; therefore, all variables will be discarded when process exits.

I think everyone will agree that there are benefits and drawbacks to each method. You just have to decide which one is better for your use case.

```
## Test for variables declared by the script:
echo "test_var3='Some Other Value'" > ./myTest3.sh
bash ./myTest3.sh
echo $test_var3
source ./myTest3.sh
echo $test_var3
```

[image: Testing setting environment variables by the script]

```
## Test for usability of current environment variables:
test_var="Some Value" # Setting a variable
echo "echo $test_var" > myTest2.sh # Creating a test script
chmod +x ./myTest2.sh # Adding execute permission
## Executing:
. myTest2.sh
bash ./myTest2.sh
source ./myTest2.sh
./myTest2.sh
## All of the above results should print the variable.
```

[image: Testing access to environment variables with different execution methods.]

I hope this helps.

Comment: An issue with sourcing scripts instead of running them in a subprocess is that the script can alter your invoking (interactive) shell's environment. (e.g. mess with your `PATH`, change the prompt, set unexpected options, modify shell variables, set signal handlers, etc)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg, Have you ran into such situation and were you able to reproduce it? I haven't encountered such behaviour, which is why I don't believe it to be the case. I will update my answer with example.

Comment: A quick sample would be `echo PS1=test > test.sh; bash test.sh # no change to prompt in shell that called the script` `source test.sh # changes the calling shell's prompt`. (`source` is meant for this type of thing...)